# Query / Find a document by an Embedmany document's id in Doctrine ODM

Tags: doctrine, odm

.......
->createQueryBuilder( 'Model\Document\Post' )
->field( 'comments.id' )->equals( $commentId ) ....
Does not work, but when comments are ReferenceMany it works. Is such query not possible when EmbedMany relation

No need to mention 'comments' refers to an EmbedMany document in a post document

Comment: Are you sure that your embedded Comments have an **id** value ? What is the raw result of your Post document ?